# How to close socket after python fail?

Tags: python, sockets, python-2.7

First, I encountered sockets in Python and faced this problem: when some error in my python code occurs, for example some syntax error before `conn.close()` on the second script start port is in use. The script already finished, but the socket is still open, kind of like busy socket.

Here is an error just for example:

```
web@web-X501A1 /var/www $ cd /home/web/www/public/py
web@web-X501A1 ~/www/public/py $ python sockets.py
connected: ('127.0.0.1', 47168)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sockets.py", line 164, in <module>
    data = re.find('(<onvif>.*<\/onvif>)')
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'find'
web@web-X501A1 ~/www/public/py $ python sockets.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sockets.py", line 154, in <module>
    sock.bind(('', 9090))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 224, in meth
    return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
socket.error: [Errno 98] Address already in use
web@web-X501A1 ~/www/public/py $ python sockets.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sockets.py", line 154, in <module>
    sock.bind(('', 9090))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 224, in meth
    return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
socket.error: [Errno 98] Address already in use
```

Code:

```
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock.bind(('', 9090))
sock.listen(1)
conn, addr = sock.accept()

try:
    print 'connected:', addr

    buffer = ''

    while True:
        buffer += conn.recv(1024)
        data = re.find('(<code>.*<\/code>)', buffer)
        print data
        exit();
        if not data:
            continue
        conn.send(data.upper())
except Exception:
    pass
finally:
    conn.close()
```

Comment: `except` the error and close the connection in a `finally` perhaps

Comment: @TimCastelijns still the same.

Comment: Still the same in what way? Can you show us the code?

Comment: I think you need `sock.close()` in your finally block as well.

Comment: @Trengot nope, same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is the dirty socket closing which occurs when the script crashes without the proper TCP connection shutdown sequence. Thankfully there's a simple solution which tells the kernel to ignore the fact the socket is already in use (the port it's bound to):

```
sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
```

That's all, add that before the bind call and you're set. Debugging your other errors will be much simpler and less time consuming once that's done ;) See more in the docs https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html#socket.socket.setsockopt

Comment: Sorry, didn't realize that the snippet wasn't the full script and appears to be disconnecting and reconnecting, you should also try to do a proper sock.shutdown() before *any* sock.close() calls https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html#socket.socket.shutdown as described here: https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html#socket.socket.close close() is one-sided.

Comment: What is the role of the last argument `1` in this line of the code?

Comment: See the man page of `setsockopt` for all the details, but in shorts: it's an int acting as a boolean value. 0 means disabled, anything non-zero means enabled.

If you're comparing this to the man page: SOL_SOCKET is the layer, SO_REUSEADDR is the option_name, and 1 is the option_value ( https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/functions/setsockopt.html )

Answer (score 2):

Enclose the usage of the socket in a try/finally clause. Close the socket in the `finally` part. Perhaps handle the exception in an `except` part. Something similar to this:

```
try:
    result = x / y
except ZeroDivisionError:
    print "division by zero!"
else:
    print "result is", result
finally:
    print "executing finally clause"
```

Comment: And by "usage of the socket" I mean the code that may raise an exception, such as line 164 in your case. So when that line breaks, the finally clause will close your connection and the next run will be fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `netstat -nutap` you should notice that you connection seems like it's still up, on a state named `TIME_WAIT`.

That's part of  TCP protocol, and according to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol#Protocol_operation):

> represents waiting for enough time to pass to be sure the remote TCP
>   received the acknowledgment of its connection termination request.
>   [According to RFC 793 a connection can stay in TIME-WAIT for a maximum
>   of four minutes known as a MSL (maximum segment lifetime).]

So, when you try to reconnect immediately to the same port, python complains that this port is still busy and cant be bound yet, saying:

```
socket.error: [Errno 98] Address already in use
```

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2351465/2304215) old question, where it is asked how to avoid this waiting time.

Comment: Is it possible somehow to ignore this? For example in PHP there is no such thing.